# Reusing trackBy functions

Tags: angular, angular-template

In Angular 11, can you apply a `trackBy` function to different loops if they have identical data types?

For example, say I am looping over two different arrays of Employee objects. Could I do this?

Component:

```
public trackEmployees(index: number, item: Employee): number {
    return item.id;
}
```

Template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let employee of entryLevelEmployees$ | async; trackBy: trackEmployees">
    <li>{{ employee.name }}</li>
</ul>

<ul *ngFor="let employee of managers$ | async; trackBy: trackEmployees">
    <li>{{ employee.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the trackBy function is used to  register a rendered element using the returned string PER *ngFor loop. So this should be valid even if the trackBy potentially returns the same ID in both *ngFor loops.